# gpg symmetric brute force using dictionary

Tags: dictionary, gnupg, brute-force

Is there any library or software which can crack gpg symmetric key based on dictionary? Can the famous John the Ripper do such job?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the passphrase is weak or strong.  Some of the passphrases people use could be defeated through a brute force attack, but the symmetric encryption in a standard OpenPGP message uses very large, randomly generated passphrases which are in excess of 60 characters (usually around 64 to 66 or so).

Brute forcing these messages would take a while, due to the actual decryption attempt rather than using rainbow tables and the like.  It also would not result in a compromise of any of the public keys, even if a single message was compromised.

Contrary to popular belief, OpenPGP messages are not wholely encrypted to the public keys of the recipients.  They are symmetrically encrypted with a randomly generated session key and then that key is encrypted to the public keys of the recipients.  When someone receives an encrypted message they use their private key to decrypt the session key, which their software (e.g. GPG or PGP) uses to decrypt the message.